# LUA и math random, массив

Tags: lua

Всем привет! Есть вопрос по поводу таблиц, массивов.

```
local myTable = {
    {"var1", "var2"},
    {"var3", "var4"},
    {"var5", "var6"}
}
```

Вот таблица, так вот, как мне вытянуть из нее рандомно либо `var1`,`var2` (чтобы именно выдернулось и `var1` и `var2` вслед за `var1`), либо `var3`,`var4`?

То есть на выходе получилось бы так:

```
local v1 = var1
local v2 = var2
```

Только как такое реализовать, я научился выдёргивать только одно значение вот так:

```
local myTable = {"bad","good","normal"}
local array = myTable[math.random(#myTable)]
print(array)
"bad"
```

А вот как получить из верхней таблицы два параметра, хз

Я не умею делать с таблицей такого типа:

```
local myTable = {
    {"var1", "var2"},
    {"var3", "var4"},
    {"var5", "var6"}
}
```

Две вещи, первая, не знаю как из первой строки вытащить сразу два параметра, второе, не умею вытаскивать получается два последовательных параметра в фигурной скобке рандомно, научите, буду признателен) пояснил как смог

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доступ к многомерному массиву осуществляется через квадратные скобки [][] (индекс в lua начинается с 1) :

```
local myTable = {
    {"var1", "var2"},
    {"var3", "var4"},
    {"var5", "var6"}
}

print(myTable[1][1]) -- var1
print(myTable[1][2]) -- var2
```

Чтобы сгенерировать случайное число ещё обычно используют [math.randomseed](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial) (для установки начального значения псевдослучайного генератора math.random):

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local n = math.random(#myTable)
print(myTable[n][1],myTable[n][2])
local array = { myTable[n][1],myTable[n][2] }    
print(array[1],array[2])
```

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы уже добавили это своим комментарием

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> local myTable = {
>   {"var1", "var2"},
>   {"var3", "var4"},
>   {"var5", "var6"}
> }
> ```

таким образом вы создаёте «таблицу таблиц» (или «массив массивов», или «список списков», если угодно).

> ```
> local array = myTable[math.random(#myTable)]
> ```

таким образом вы получаете «срез» из «таблицы таблиц», который, в свою очередь, сам является таблицей, состоящей (в вашем случае) из двух элементов.

эти два элемента можно сразу же присвоить двум переменным, воспользовавшись:

- [множественным присваиванием](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.1.html) (`var1, var2 = что-то-возвращающее-два-значения`)
- [функцией `unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack)

```
local v1,v2 = unpack( myTable[math.random(#myTable)] )
```

---

и, конечно, если используете `math.random()`, в начале программы надо инициализировать последовательность ([рекомендуют использовать](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial) `os.time()` — `math.randomseed( os.time() )`)

---

#### итого

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )

local myTable = {
    {"var1", "var2"},
    {"var3", "var4"},
    {"var5", "var6"}
}

local v1,v2 = unpack( myTable[math.random(#myTable)] )

print ("v1="..v1.."; v2="..v2)
```

последовательные запуски скрипта вернут разные результаты:

```
$ lua скрипт
v1=var3; v2=var4
$ lua скрипт
v1=var1; v2=var2
```